# Implement Bucket Partitioning in Cloud Storage from a Teradata Data Source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, teradata, partitioning

Has anyone successfully implemented partitioning in GCS where the source is Teradata? I'm using the WRITE_NOS functionality but I am unable to create the partitions in GCS because I cannot create a key-value pair for the partition name that GCS requires. Consider:

WRITE_NOS OUTPUT: gs://bucket/table/YYYY-MM-DD
GCS Expected: gs://bucket/table/dt=YYYY-MM-DD

I am unable to add the "dt=" before the date value. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you let Teradata create files with just the partitioning value, then use CUSTOM schema detection `gs://bucket/table/{dt:DATE}` to access from Google Cloud?

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Do you mean use a different strategy other than performing WRITE_NOS?

Comment: No, I mean use WRITE_NOS but when reading on GC side explicitly specify a custom schema rather than default auto discovery.